# Delete specific cookie in chrome extension when the icon clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

this is my first program and i'm getting lost..
I try to do an extension that delete one cookie from specific web when I click on the icon of this extension.
What's wrong with my code?

Thank you all!

manifest.json:

```
    {    
  "name" : "Delete Cookie",
  "version" : "0.8",
  "manifest_version": 2
  "description" : "Delete Cookie by icon clicked",
  "permissions": [ "cookies", "http://www.example.com" ],
  "icons": { "16": "cookie.png", "48": "cookie.png", "128": "cookie.png" },
  "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "cookie.png"
  },
  "background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

}
```

backgroung.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(DeletCookie) 
function DeletCookie()  
{  
      chrome.cookies.remove({url:"http://www.example.com", name: "CookieName"})  
}
```

## EDIT

I tried this:

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({domain: "www.example.com"}, function(cookies) {
for(var i=0; i<cookies.length;i++) {
  console.log(cookies[i]);

  chrome.cookies.remove({url: "https://" + cookies[i].domain  + cookies[i].path, name: cookies[i].name});
}
```

});

and it worked,but this way it delete the cookie every time it shwoes up.

So I try:

```
function DeleteCookie (){
   chrome.cookies.getAll({domain: "www.example.com"}, function(cookies) {
       for(var i=0; i<cookies.length;i++) {
        console.log(cookies[i]);

        chrome.cookies.remove({url: "https://" + cookies[i].domain  +           cookies[i].path, name: cookies[i].name});
       }
    });   
}; 
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(DeletCookie) ;
```

and this way it doesn't work again

Comment: What does the extension do when you run it? Are there any error messages?

Comment: Nothing happens, the cookie still there

Comment: Have you tried to use `chrome.cookies.remove`'s callback function and check for `chrome.runtime.lastError` there?

Comment: I edit the massege.

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: @Dean There is a typo where you attached the listener. `DeletCookie` instead of `DeleteCookie`. I don't know if that's just a typo on here or if that's the exact code you are running but I thought I'd mention.

Comment: is that `DeleteCookie` solved your problem?

Comment: yes ! (it workes with the last try I post in the edit section, the original one still doesn't work but it's ok for me)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this thing in my extension

```
delete_cookie('cookies_name');

var delete_cookie = function(name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
};
```

that work fine for me.