# Chrome Cookies Remover API not working although it returns the results

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to delete all the cookies from a website. Although the callback from `chrome.cookies.remove` says that the cookies have been deleted but when I refreshed the website, the cookies info are still tracking from the previous session.

For instance, I'm trying to delete a cookie named `visited_stories` in a website as shown in the image below:

[image: Website Cookies]

Below is my background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        if (tab.url.includes(targetUrl)) {
            chrome.cookies.getAll({"domain": ".example.com"}, function(cookies) {
                console.log('Cookies before delete:::', cookies)
                for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    chrome.cookies.remove({ url: "http://example.com" + cookies[i].path, name: cookies[i].name }, function(removedCookies) {
                        console.log('Cookies deleted:::', removedCookies)
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Although, in my console, the `chrome.cookies.remove` returns the removed cookies which contains `visited_stories` but it is still contains data from previous session (adding on to the array of visited stories).

The cookie will only reset again if I delete it manually from the browser. Hence, I am not sure if `chrome.cookies.remove` has actually removed the cookies. How can I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37803265/3825777

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS, I've injected the code below but it doesn't seem to work for me. 

function delete_cookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
};

delete_cookie('visited_stories');